# Exit code 1 does not fail my GitHub actions step

Tags: docker-compose, github-actions, exit-code

I'm trying to run tests(Karate) using GitHub actions and even if the build fails(failing test) and results in exit code 1, the Github step passes.

My workflow file:

```
name: Run E2E tests
on: pull_request

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run karate tests
        run: make test 

      - name: Karate DSL Test Reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Test Reports
          path: ./target/cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html
```

My make command is simply running a docker container(with maven dependencies) and has the following:

```
test:
    docker-compose up --build
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  karate-tests:
    image: karate-tests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./target:/usr/src/app/target
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    command: mvn --batch-mode test
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-jdk-11

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app/
COPY /src/test/java /usr/src/app/src/test/java
```

GitHub actions showing that the step is successful despite a failing build:
[image]

Can anyone help me figure out why the step passes even if the build fails(exit code 1)?

Update: I found that if I run "mvn test" directly then the step fails as expected. So it seems to be related to the make command that I'm running.

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what does `make test` _do_?

Comment: test exited with code 1 but probably whole make didn't

Comment: Thanks for checking guys :) I just updated the description with the make command. It's just to run a docker container. As @GrzegorzKrukowski mentioned, I tried running "mvn test" directly instead of "make test" and then the step fails properly. So it's something to do with the make command but I'm still at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add the argument `--exit-code-from` while running the Docker container and that helped GitHub actions to identify the exit code properly.

Comment: Do you know if something like this exist for docker run also? Im having a similiar problem? npm run build fails with exit code 1, but the github action step still goes forward.